# Foreign Keys in Databases

Tags: mysql, database

This table should contain foreign keys to allow sensible links to be made with the other two tables, together with the dates of each exam.

So what am i being asked to do exactly?
All the other tables have been populated.

Comment: They are wanting you to create a junction table between subjects and students as many students will have many subjects.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not here to solve your homework. Use the search engine and search for many-to-many relationship

Comment: Hi again so I have done what you suggested but what about the date of each exam as I can only think of adding it by using a select command and I am not even sure if that is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a classic Many To Many relational problem.

One student can study more than one subject

A subject can be studied by more than student

This cannot be readily modelled relationally using just the two tables you have given.

The traditional way to model this is to introduce a third table which contains the details of which students are studying which subjects.

The table would generally contain the id's of the tables that participate in the many to many relationship, so in your case it would have student_id and subjects_id. These would be defined with foreign key constraints back to the student and subjects tables.

This [page](http://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20ERwin%20Data%20Modeler%20r8-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/Methods/index.htm?toc.htm?254546.html) may go a long way to helping you understand this.

By the way - the primary key constraint on the subjects table looks a bit suspect to me ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, ignore the primary key I copied an old file but I have not fixed it.

Comment: Hi again so I have done what you suggested but what about the date of each exam as I can only think of adding it by using a select command and I am not even sure if that is right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you should do with the date of the exam - as far as I am concerned it makes no sense to put it on the link table - that would imply that different students could do the exam on different dates.

Comment: Oh okay I will just have to find a way as i cant just leave it out but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your PRIMARY KEY of the subject table should be subjects_id, because you may have 2 final exams the same day.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
    entry_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,( PK)
    student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,(FK From students table)
    subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,(FK From subjects table )
);
```

You need to make (student_id,subject_id) combination unique since it shouldn't be duplicated.This is rough draft.Assume that this table is a bridge which connects students and subjects.